# How to manually update Google APIs Intel x86 System Image?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've downloaded `x86-25_r07.zip`in browser instead of downloading it in Android Studio.
How to install it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you need to extract the zip file in its respective `system-images` folder.

The path in Windows OS will be: `{username}\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\android-25\google_apis\x86_64`

Where `android-25` is the version, which in your case is 25.

The path in Linux & Mac will be respective to SDK's `system-images` folder path as SDK images does not change & are independent of OS.

If any similar system image exists on the same path, just create a new folder for your downloaded zip and extract it into that new folder. If no folder exists, then create one.

Inside `android-25` folder, if your downloaded image is `Google APIs` then the folder name should be `google_apis`, if the downloaded image is `Google APIs with Play Store` then folder name must be `google_apis_playstore`

Note: This answer is based on my knowledge & previous experience in Windows, I do not hold any responsibility if you mess anything in your SDK. I strongly recommend you to first have a closer look at all the directories and folders under `system-images` folder to have a better understanding and easier solution.